# How can I know if python 3 is using cPickle or Pickle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, pickle

I saw these two answers about Pickle and cPickle having dealt automatically by python 3, transparent to the user:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49579373/1273751
- https://askubuntu.com/a/804618/315699

How can I know if in python 3, it is using the fast version (cPickle) or not? I want to force it to use cPickle. My main interest is not even on the speed, but on the shorter size of the files, since I am generating files that end up being bigger than 1 GB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you build your Python binary from source, you almost certainly are using the C extension.

However, if you must be certain, check if the `_pickle` module can be imported:

```
>>> import _pickle
```

The [`pickle` module imports `_pickle`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d93fbbf88e4abdd24a0a55e3ddf85b8420c62052/Lib/pickle.py#L1598-L1613) and only if that fails with an `ImportError` would it be using the pure-Python implementation.

Just to be explicit: what was called `cPickle` in Python 2 has been renamed to `_pickle` and is imported transparently, you don't have to do anything explicit to make use of it. That there was a split between `pickle` and `cPickle` in Python 2 was just plain confusing.

Comment: would I know if the import failed?

Comment: Then `ImportError` is raised. It’s just a module, either it is available and so will be used, or the import fails with the usual `ImportError` exception.

Comment: Wouldn't `ImportError`  be treated internally, instead of printing it to me, since it will just import the pure python pickle module instead?

Comment: I never installed cPickle manually, so I just want to make sure it is using that. I will test importing `_pickle` to see if anything changes

Comment: You can still determine if the `_pickle` module can be imported. If it can, then it won’t fail to import when you use the `pickle` module.

Comment: Again, there is no cPickle module in Python 3. That module was replaced with `_pickle` in Python 3.