# How to resolve 'No module named 'cPickle'' exception in virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm trying to run a program which connects to all databases(mysql,sqlite) and fetch data from it .

Python version - 3.6.8

Since the code is too long ,i'm showing only particular snippets.

```py
def show_columns_mysql(cursor,tbname):
    cursor.execute("""show columns from %s"""%(tbname))
    rs=cursor.fetchall()
    colname=[]
    for i in rs:
        colname.append(i[0])
    return colname
```

There is no problem or issue if i exexute the program in normal python environment . When i try to execute this in virtual environment ,it shows me **No module named 'cPickle'** .

I have tried all the solutions but none solved my problem .

What was the problem  ?

Comment: are you using `six` package by any chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find module cPickle using Python 3.5 and Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579282/cant-find-module-cpickle-using-python-3-5-and-anaconda)

Comment: no i'm not using it .some people suggested to use six package .so when i checked using pip show six , it is installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cPickle in Python 3. Just import pickle. pickle will automatically use the C accelerator.

Comment: Im not at all using pickle anywhere . Then where i need to use **import pickle** ???

Comment: If you are not using the ```pickle``` anywhere, you can remove the line where you imported it.

Comment: @DipeshPaudel I'm not using the import pickle statement anywhere in my program with respect to knowledge and it still throws the exception .

Comment: what line number throws the exception?  what's on that line?

Comment: might be possibilities that your external files are might be using it check the error to which file error was created it will help in debug

Answer (score -1):

Install `pickle`. Then do:

```
import pickle as cPickle
```

Comment: when i try to install pickle : 
Collecting pickle
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pickle