# Is there a way to serialize/deserialize without engaging the python GIL

Tags: python, python-3.6, pickle, python-multithreading

A quick test shows that cPickle (python 3.6.9 `import pickle` [defaults to using cPickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579282/cant-find-module-cpickle-using-python-3-5-and-anaconda)) engages the GIL.

```
import pickle
import os

big_data = os.urandom(10000000)

def run():
    pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(big_data))

t = timeit.Timer(run)
[threading.Thread(target=lambda: t.timeit(number=2000)).start() for _ in range(4)]
```

That test of 4 threads running serialization operations runs at 100% cpu, e.g. it engages the GIL. The same type of test running a numpy operation uses 400% cpu (no GIL engaged with numpy).

I was hoping cPickle, being a C function, wouldn't engage the GIL. Is there any way around this? I'd like to be able to deserialize a large amount of data without blocking the main process.

I am trying to pull in upward of 3GB of data per second from worker processes back to main. I can move the data with streaming sockets and asyncio at 4GB/sec, but the deserialization is a bottleneck. **[I don't have the luxury of Python 3.8](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374) and SharedMemory yet unfortunately.**

An acceptable answer is, of course, a confident No.

Comment: I don't see why the fact that the the module is a C-extension should make you think that it wouldn't engage the GIL. From my understanding, the fundamental problem the GIL solves is thread-safe access to Python interpreter level objects which rely on reference counting for garbage collection. Since `pickle` serialization/deserialization touches Python objects that other threads might have access to, it has to engage the GIL.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'll accept that if you post that as an answer. Your explanation sounds quite likely to be correct.  I was equating C functions to external functions that can release the GIL as numpy does, but as you point out that doesn't seem reasonable in the case of Python object serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @juanpa.arrivillaga's answer from comments to close this question:

I don't see why the fact that the the module is a C-extension should make you think that it wouldn't engage the GIL. From my understanding, the fundamental problem the GIL solves is thread-safe access to Python interpreter level objects which rely on reference counting for garbage collection. Since pickle serialization/deserialization touches Python objects that other threads might have access to, it has to engage the GIL.